# Birds eye view of how to place video's into Facebook timelines

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sharer

We're trying to have users share 'articles' on a simple website into their timelines. Each article is associated with a video and we would like to use that video in the representation of the article in a users timeline. Now, I've read that linking to an mp4 via open graph meta tags isn't possible anymore. So I presume I should be using the graph api.

Could someone confirm that this is true?
And if so can you give a quick run down of the necessary steps achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: To keep news feed cleaner, they decided to not play videos on shared articles inline any more - clicking will now take the user to the external page, and they can view the video there if they like. And the API won’t help in that regard either (at most you could let users upload the actual video, so that it becomes part of their videos on Facebook, but that’s something completely different than sharing of course.)

Comment: Would you know, if there is any official information about this change?

Comment: Got nothing “official” right now, but news articles such as https://www.recode.net/2018/1/31/16957546/facebook-time-spent-decline-mark-zuckerberg-explanation-q4-earnings-2018, https://www.recode.net/2018/2/12/17006362/facebook-news-feed-change-meaningful-interactions-definition-measure talk about the broader changes Facebook is making in regard to news feed and videos.

Comment: Could we use the graph API to upload a mp4 and post it like so this one https://share.bushbaby.nl/3PWlfhJ9qS/ ?

Comment: That is a Facebook video, yes, and it should be shareable like any other content on Facebook.